# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I tried to use Retrofit with invoke() method but an error occurred

```
    suspend {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(WeatherApi::class.java)
            .getPost("-33.8523341", "151.2106085", "***********API**********")

    }.invoke()
```

getPost() Method

```
@GET("onecall?units=metric")
fun getPost(
    @Query("lat") lat: String,
    @Query("lon") lon: String,
    @Query("APPID") app_id: String
): WeatherData
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for 
                      class com.example.weatherapp.data.responses.WeatherData
                      for method WeatherApi.getPost
```

Comment: Use either Call<WeatherData> or Deferred<WeatherData>. However, Deferred requires the kotlin.coroutines library but it reduces boilerplate code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@GET("onecall?units=metric")
suspend fun getPost(               //use suspend
    @Query("lat") lat: String,
    @Query("lon") lon: String,
    @Query("APPID") app_id: String
): WeatherData
```